# Naming entries of one column after grouping by entries of other column

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
In [52]: df = pd.DataFrame({'orderNr':[1,2,3,4,5],'customer':['name2','name2','name1','name3','name3']})

In [53]: df
Out[53]: 
  customer  orderNr
0    name2        1
1    name2        2
2    name1        3
3    name3        4
4    name3        5
```

I would like to group the orderNr by the customers that placed the order and then change the orderNr-values accordingly like so:

```
   customer      orderNr
 0    name2        name2
 1    name1        name1
 2    name3        name3
```

I thought I could do this with:

```
def f(group):
    group.orderNr = group.name
    return group

df.groupby('customer' ,as_index = False)['orderNr'].apply(f)
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Also I feel like there should be a more elegant way using pandas' .map() method.
If I could implement something using the mapping

```
customer_map={"name1":1,"name2":2,"name3":3}
```

that would be neat. Then I could just save the orderNr as integer.

Comment: Why not just `df['orderNr'] = df.customer`?

Comment: Of course! Seeing this I also realise what I meant to do is not sensible as I'll end up having the exact same information in two columns. Thank you.